# Octave Install Failing on Mac OS X 10.7.4 (using homebrew)

Tags: osx-lion, octave, homebrew

I am trying to setup octave on my macbook pro via homebrew. My homebrew is updated, as is my XCode and its command line tools.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_append_history", referenced from:
      _octave_append_history in liboctave_la-oct-rl-hist.o
     (maybe you meant: _octave_append_history)
  "_history_list", referenced from:
      _octave_history_list in liboctave_la-oct-rl-hist.o
     (maybe you meant: _octave_history_list)
  "_read_history_range", referenced from:
      _octave_read_history_range in liboctave_la-oct-rl-hist.o
     (maybe you meant: _octave_read_history_range)
  "_rl_basic_quote_characters", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_set_basic_quote_characters in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
  "_rl_char_is_quoted_p", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_set_char_is_quoted_function in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
  "_rl_clear_screen", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_clear_screen in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
     (maybe you meant: _octave_rl_clear_screen)
  "_rl_filename_dequoting_function", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_set_dequoting_function in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
  "_rl_filename_quote_characters", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_set_filename_quote_characters in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
  "_rl_filename_quoting_desired", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_filename_quoting_desired in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
     (maybe you meant: _octave_rl_filename_quoting_desired)
  "_rl_filename_quoting_function", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_set_quoting_function in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
  "_rl_free_undo_list", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_clear_undo_list in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
  "_rl_history_search_backward", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_history_search_backward in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
     (maybe you meant: _octave_rl_history_search_backward)
  "_rl_history_search_forward", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_history_search_forward in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
     (maybe you meant: _octave_rl_history_search_forward)
  "_rl_re_read_init_file", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_set_name in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
      _octave_rl_re_read_init_file in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
     (maybe you meant: _octave_rl_re_read_init_file)
  "_rl_resize_terminal", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_resize_terminal in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
     (maybe you meant: _octave_rl_resize_terminal)
  "_rl_undo_list", referenced from:
      _octave_rl_clear_undo_list in liboctave_la-oct-rl-edit.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [liboctave.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My Build Environment:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.3
HEAD: bb9952a88dab92850145c2ebca797429f43e1839
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.7.4-x86_64
Xcode: 4.5
CLT: 1.0.0.9000000000.1.1249367152
X11: 2.6.4 => /usr/X11
CC: cc
CXX: c++
LD: cc
CFLAGS: -D_REENTRANT
CXXFLAGS: -D_REENTRANT
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local/opt/texinfo:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/X11/include/freetype2:/usr/include/libxml2:/usr/X11/include
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/X11/lib
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/share/pkgconfig
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Many thanks in advance for any pointers you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem by installing a GCC compiler from the high performance computing website:

http://hpc.sourceforge.net/